# how to make a rails auto filler in form with data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How do I make a method to auto fill a field in a form for "EmployeeNumber"

code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
              <div class="mini_jumbotron">
                <div class="mini_text">numemp<%= image_tag("calendar.png", :class => "calendar")%>
                  </div> <br>
                </div>
              <%= f.text_field :numemp %>
```

I want this numemp to be auto filled by the column "employee number" on the "users" table,

Is there any way to do this?

How do I do it?

Comment: What is the datatype of employee number?

Comment: decimal, and I wanted it to grab the employee number from the current_user

Comment: How would you expect a value of *decimal datatype* to fill in for `datetime_field`?

Comment: I corrected it, and that is not what I asked >.>

Comment: Ok. What is the field name exactly? `employee_number`?

Comment: `:NumeroEmpregado`

Comment: Is that the field name? Can you please do `User.column_names` in the console and print the result here?

Comment: The column name is NumeroEmpregado... the new field that i want the form to write this NumeroEmpregado into another column in another table as numemp ...

Comment: Ok. Try `<%= f.text_field :numemp, current_user.NumeroEmpregado %>`

Comment: `undefined method "merge" for "1221":String` 1221 is the NumeroEmpregado

Comment: Try `<%= f.text_field :numemp, value: current_user.NumeroEmpregado %>`

Comment: worked, thanks! Submit it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: worked, thanks! Submit it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work

```
<%= f.text_field :numemp, value: current_user.NumeroEmpregado %>
```

*Small Note:*

I recommend to follow *rails conventions*. By convention all **column names** should be in `snake_case`